# Codewars Snail Test Wrong or Code Wrong?

Tags: arrays, ruby, testing, recursion

I think I have a pretty cool solution to this [codewars](http://www.codewars.com/kata/snail/train/ruby) challenge but I am failing the last test because it is adding an extra 1 to the beginning of my array and I don't know why! In IRB my code seems to work fine.

```
@arr = []

def snail(array)
  array.to_a.empty? ? (return @arr.flatten) : @arr << array.shift
  snail(array.transpose.reverse)
end
```

When `snail([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])` expected `[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]` but got `[1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `@arr` isn't being cleared between tests. So, presumably, the test before the failing one was something like `snail([[1]])`, which would make `@arr = [[1]]` (which when flattened, adds an extra `1` to the front).

The solution would be to clear `@arr` when you finish a particular test case, something like the following would do it:

```
@arr = []

def snail(array)
  if array.to_a.empty?
    output = @arr.flatten
    @arr = []

    return output
  else
    @arr << array.shift
  end
  snail(array.transpose.reverse)
end
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks that makes sense!  I always assumed I would want to keep @arr each recursion and didn't think about it in that way. Learning so much... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def snail(array)
  head, *tail = array
  head ? head + snail(tail.transpose.reverse) : []
end

arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
snail(arr) #=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Nice. It may read better to replace `array[0] ?` with `array.any? ?` or `array.empty? ?` (and, for the latter, reverse what follows).